# Bool must be a Chisel type, not hardware

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I am learning the design of `SonicBoom`. I added a signal is_uni to the `MicroOp` class.

https://github.com/riscv-boom/riscv-boom/blob/master/src/main/scala/exu/execution-units/functional-unit.scala

I added the following code to the `PipelinedMulUnit` class in the above link. I want to delay the `is_uni` signal by `numStages` cycles, because I found that the `multiplier` also delayed so many cycles before outputting the result.

```
val uni_signal = Valid( io.req.bits.uop.is_uni )
uni_signal.valid := io.req.valid
```

The following error occurred.

```
Bool(Wire in PipelinedMulUnit)' must be a Chisel type, not hardware
```

I changed to

```
  val uni_signal = Valid( chiselTypeOf(io.req.bits.uop.is_unicore ))
  uni_signal.valid := io.req.valid
```

The following error occurred again:

```
chisel3.package$ExpectedHardwareException: data to be connected 'Bool' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type. Perhaps you forgot to wrap it in Wire(_) or IO(_)?
```

I added Wire() as prompted.

```
   val uni_signal = Valid( wire(chiselTypeOf(io.req.bits.uop.is_uni) ))
      uni_signal.valid := io.req.valid
```

The following error occurred again:

```
Bool(Wire in PipelinedMulUnit)' must be a Chisel type, not hardware
```

I would like to ask what should I do? What type does it need?

Comment: Have you really added `Wire()` in the last sentence ? It do not appear on last code presented.

Comment: Yes. I corrected it.